# It it okay to ignore cookieless users

Tags: http, session, cookies

Hey, need to know some stats on the percentage of users who browse the internet cookieless? Anyone know where to find this?

Answer (score 0):

No, don't ignore cookie-disabled users. Though cookies are better for session management as it does things like prevent accidental spoofing (give a link with the session ID to your friend, and she's logged in as you), you should still fall back to 'session ID in the URI' if you detect that cookies are not enabled (this is not hard); you should not rely on cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is such report covers general users. I think it depends on the users or devices you are targeting. It is always better not to ignore cookieless users but if you do not mind loosing some opportunity cost, then you can analyse your web traffic and see how many percent of users accessed your website had cookie disabled. If this number is significant, you should consider support cookieless access.